# Reverse a number algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, integer

I was thinking of ways to reverse an integer and I came up with this one:

```
num = 123456
power = len(str(num))
result = 0
for i in range(1, power):
    result += (num % 10) * 10**(power - i)
    num = int(num / 10)
result += num

print(result)
```

I was going through algorithms of other people and I haven't seen anyone using this method with exponents.

For example his one is not mine:

```
public long  reverse(long x)
    {
        long result = 0;
        while (x != 0)
        {
            result = result * 10 + x % 10;
            x = x / 10;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Is my algorithm inferior? Like, will it take more time to calculate the reversed number because of the exponent part?

Comment: I should have clarified that I want to reverse the number as a number, not a string.  It wasn't meant to be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` and `for` loops go through the same number of iterations in both solutions. So it is not inferior in that sense.

Your solution contains a conversion from a numeric to a string so yes that can be avoided. But since Python allows you do such conversions easily and if that improves the readability of your code then that doesn't make your code inferior in my opinion. Although, having said that consider the solution proposed in the comments to the question :)

Comment: Oh, I understand. Now the solution feels kind of stupid. I wanted to reverse an integer using only math but I converted it to a string anyway. The second solution is pure math so I guess it's better that way.